# MariaDB stops responding unexpectedly

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have noticed for the second time this week that the MySQL (MariaDB 5.5) stopped responding unexpectedly. Once I do restart, it starts working normally. The database is for a Moodle (LMS) server.

Below are the Details :

`cat /var/lib/mysql/mydb.example.com.err`

```
200531 12:03:54 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Normal shutdown
200531 12:03:54 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
200531 12:03:54  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
200531 12:03:55  InnoDB: Waiting for 82 pages to be flushed
200531 12:03:58  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 500510306139
200531 12:03:58 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
200531 12:03:58 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/mydb.example.com.pid ended
200531 12:03:59 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
200531 12:03:59 [Warning] 'THREAD_CONCURRENCY' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
200531 12:03:59 [Warning] option 'max_allowed_packet': unsigned value 10485760000 adjusted to 1073741824
200531 12:03:59 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.61-MariaDB) starting as process 62524 ...
200531 12:03:59 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
200531 12:03:59 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
200531 12:03:59 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
200531 12:03:59 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
200531 12:03:59 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
200531 12:04:00 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
200531 12:04:00 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
200531 12:04:00  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
200531 12:04:01 Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.5.59-MariaDB-38.11 started; log sequence number 500510306139
200531 12:04:01 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
200531 12:04:01 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
200531 12:04:01 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
200531 12:04:01 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.61-MariaDB'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server

200605  9:12:59 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Normal shutdown
200605  9:12:59 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
200605  9:12:59  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
200605  9:13:00  InnoDB: Waiting for 57 pages to be flushed
200605  9:13:04  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 503608227899
200605  9:13:04 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

200605 09:13:04 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/lib/mysql/mydb.example.com.pid ended
200605 09:13:06 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
200605  9:13:06 [Warning] 'THREAD_CONCURRENCY' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
200605  9:13:06 [Warning] option 'max_allowed_packet': unsigned value 10485760000 adjusted to 1073741824
200605  9:13:06 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.61-MariaDB) starting as process 34997 ...
200605  9:13:06 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
200605  9:13:06 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
200605  9:13:06 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
200605  9:13:06 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
200605  9:13:06 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
200605  9:13:06 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
200605  9:13:06 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
200605  9:13:07  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
200605  9:13:08 Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.5.59-MariaDB-38.11 started; log sequence number 503608227899
200605  9:13:08 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
200605  9:13:08 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
200605  9:13:08 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
200605  9:13:08 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.61-MariaDB'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server
```

`cat /etc/my.cnf`

```
[client]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock


[mysqld]
port            = 3306
socket          = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 384M
max_allowed_packet = 10000M
table_open_cache = 512
sort_buffer_size = 2M
read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M
thread_cache_size = 8
query_cache_size = 32M

innodb_file_format = Barracuda
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_large_prefix

character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
skip-character-set-client-handshake


log-bin=mysql-bin

server-id       = 1

binlog_format=mixed
expire_logs_days=10

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
default-character-set = utf8mb4

[myisamchk]
key_buffer_size = 256M
sort_buffer_size = 256M
read_buffer = 2M
write_buffer = 2M

[mysqlhotcopy]
interactive-timeout
```

OS  : centOS 6.1

RAM :

```
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         15753      13354       2399          3        175      12091
-/+ buffers/cache:       1087      14665
Swap:         7999          0       7999
```

Comment: Can you provide CPU CORE ? Have you observe any long running query or DML statement after which  Mariadb acts abnormal ?

Comment: Additional information request. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
name; 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Are you aware your version has changed from 5.5.59 to 5.5.61 between the beginning and end of your error log?   Is your system trying to do 'auto updates'?

Comment: @JaifarAlShizawi Your request for max_allowed_packet=10000M is not permitted. The upper limit is 1G on any version of MySQL or MariaDB. And your sort_buffer_size = 2M
read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 8M    should all be removed to allow defaults to work for you and conserve RAM per connection.

Comment: Have you made any progress with your MariaDB?

Comment: @JaifarAlShizawi Have you made any progress with your MariaDB instance? Posting additional information requested Jun 5 at 16:26 would allow completing server workload tuning analysis for you.